# I want SQL query to find the balance of a all accounts on a defined date

Tags: sql-server

# acno             # balance#         # dateofentry

```
0001             55000      23/03/15
0001             5200       26/05/14
0001             8562       15/03/16
0001             85         25/03/16
0001             4562       29/06/16
0002             65         24/02/14
0002             4875       18/06/12
0002             142563     13/07/14
0002             1245       31/03/16  
0002             7896       14/05/16
0002             4575       12/08/16
'

'
'
'
'
'
'
```

here i need a query like which should give an output as on 31/03/2016

# ac.no#     # balance#       # date

```
0001            85        25/03/16
0002          1245        31/03/16
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question and the data you provided?

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you targetting?

Comment: what is the datatype of date column?

Comment: data type of date is  date

Comment: So i have given the answer does that worked for you?

Comment: no sir ....that is giving only one result

Comment: I have edited my answer does it works for you now?

Comment: i hv edited my que plz send soln fr that ...

Comment: i hv edited my answer according to your edited question, does it helps now?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following: **Updated**

```
SELECT k.salesTran, m.salesMaster FROM 
(
  SELECT salesTran, MAX(date) AS MaxDate FROM sales
  GROUP BY salesTran
) k INNER JOIN sales m
ON m.date = k.MaxDate
```

Comment: Never mind. Edited.

Comment: I think you should try your SQL before posting it, your edit is legal syntax but not what the OP wants, you will only retrieve the most recent transaction regardless of account.

Comment: I guess, the OP wants to return the transactions with recent dates.

Comment: it l gives only one record i need all records of recent transcation

Comment: What **exactly** do you want? You must be much clearer if you want good answers. What do you mean "all records"? It seems you want the most recent transaction per salestrans (whatever that is), is that correct?

Comment: Never mind for the delay @sachin. It will work fine and updated. Downvote! See the query now.

Comment: bro ,i am not getting how to ask my doubte ,,the data is different bt i cant post that one becoz of our hr so hw may i contact u personally....

Comment: No need to do that @sachin. The above query returns the expected output you provided. Now if you have anything to clear, then ask specifically.

Answer (score 0):

```
select acno,balance,dateofentry from
(
 select Row_Number() Over(Order by dateofentry desc) partition by acno  as rownum,acno ,balance,dateofentry from tablename where dateofentry<=cast('31/03/2016' as date)
) a 

where a.rownum=1
```

Comment: @Sachin does this query gives you the required output?

Comment: does this works now?

Comment: its giving an error like"The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported"..

Comment: What version of sqlserver are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2008 inbuit

Answer (score 0):

To get the output you want, in a more recent SQL Server version, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY salestrans ORDER BY salesdate DESC) AS RN
        FROM
            sales
    ) x
WHERE
    RN = 1
```

This will internally number each row as 1 for the most recent for a given salestrans, 2 for the next, etc. and then only pick out the rows that has the number 1.

However, I'm not convinced this answers your question.